# Implement infinite scrolling in yii

Tags: json, yii, infinite-scroll

I am currently using pagination with cListView. The page is completely rendered on server and send to client. Now this is what i am planning:
Just send data in json format from server and it will be renderend on client using some template engine.
Use infinite scrolling instead of pagination.

Using CListview and renderPartial i can send the json object of data to client but CListView will be sending the ajax page footer in plain html. How can i send that part in json so that i can use the existing functionality without writing trivial code for OFFSET and LIMIT in sql myself ?

Comment: Try http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/inifinite-scroll-pager or http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll

Comment: These plugins don't send data in json format. Even if i send data in json format, plugin will be sending pager information (link for next page) in plain html. I want to send pages in json.

Comment: Yii renders the pages on the server side, however only the requested amount of data is displayed. Hence everything is already optimized. The framework already did everything for you, there's no point in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You can think of putting just json data in _view file. No html. So network will only be penalized for data, not the reduntant css for each component of same type. There is no re-inventing of wheel. Basically i am movie from thin client to thick client.

Comment: I understand that, but wouldn't a js framework like Angular JS or Ember.js work better in this case? I don't see the benefit of Yii if you're not taking advantage of its core functionalities.

Comment: How are you using CListView to generate JSON representation of your dataprovider?

Comment: I can use _view file for rendering JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out TbJsonGridView at [here](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/json-grid.html). It sends all the data in json format including header, pager etc. It uses its own template library and CGridView only. If possible you may hack it to tune to your requirements.